# How to compute PSD of 2D signals

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, image-processing

I have a binary matrix $X$ that filtered by a 2D filter $H$. In MATLAB, the Output $Y$ is $Y=conv2(X,H)$. Now I want to see the effect of this filtering operation by comparing the Power Spectral Density of $X$ and $Y$. Each element $x_{ij}$ of $X$ is independent and identically distributed.

My question is :

1. How can I use fft2(.) in matlab to get PSD. This tutorial, http://faculty.olin.edu/bstorey/Notes/Fourier.pdf, explains computing PSD for 1D signals but I cant find anything similar for 2D. Can someone make a reference to a good resource.
2. How can I compute PSD for this typical input/output when H=[1 1;1 1].

MATLAB Code:

```
f = -2*(round(rand(N,N))-0.5);    
subplot(2,3,1)
imagesc(f);colormap(gray(256));axis equal;title('Input')

Af = fft2(f);    
pf = (abs(Af)).^2;
subplot(2,3,2)
imagesc(pf);colormap(gray(256));axis equal;title('PSD of Input')

Bf = fftshift(Af); % Center FFT
Bf = abs(Bf); % Get the magnitude
Bf = log(Bf+1); % Use log, for perceptual scaling, and +1 since log(0) is undefined
Bf = mat2gray(Bf); % Use mat2gray to scale the image between 0 and 1

subplot(2,3,3)
imagesc(Bf);colormap(gray(256));axis equal;title('Shifted PSD of Input')

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

h = [1 1;1 1];
y= conv2(f,h);

subplot(2,3,4)
imagesc(y);colormap(gray(256));axis equal;title('Output')

Cf = fft2(y);    
yf = (abs(Cf)).^2;
subplot(2,3,5)
imagesc(yf);colormap(gray(256));axis equal;title('PSD of Output')

Df = fftshift(Cf); % Center FFT
Df = abs(Df); % Get the magnitude
Df = log(Df+1); % Use log, for perceptual scaling, and +1 since log(0) is undefined
Df = mat2gray(Df); % Use mat2gray to scale the image between 0 and 1

subplot(2,3,6)
imagesc(Df);colormap(gray(256));axis equal;title('Shifted PSD of Output')
```

[image]

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com  after you obtain the fft of your image, you will just obtain the absolute square of every value in your matrix and your are done. Note that this is not PSD. It is just an estimate of it.

Comment: obtain the results and put the figures here and share your opinions. you will get some feedback.

Comment: Well I have posted it but it doesnt look good

Comment: it does not seem bad. however, there is something problematic here. fourier transform is symmetric. for 1D you only need the half of the data for processing or interpreting. There may be some shifting issues. please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549186/how-to-plot-a-2d-fft-in-matlab

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I interpret these PSD plots? I dont understand this part. In case of 1D signals, we get to see frequency content clearly. Here thats not the case. Can you help with the analysis part? My basic objective is to quantify the correlation at filter output.

Comment: Also, in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549186/how-to-plot-a-2d-fft-in-matlab, they are taking only abs(fft2(.)) where as you commented to take (abs(fft2(.))).^2.

Comment: the filering you do is called smothing, namely smoothing filtering. the original image you have is random image, which has frequency components scattered everywhere at the PSD. Random images have such a property. They are simply noise and noise spectrum is flat. when you do smooting, you will basically attenuate high frequency components of your noisy image. the resulting PSD then will have reduced power at high frequency bands. so the question is where is the high and where is the low frequency bins in 2D spectra? if it is the shifted version it would be at the center point of the PSD figure.

Comment: yes, but the question there is to find the fft, not power spectral density. these are two different things. I told you to have a look at that post just to see the shifting thing.